# query to display additional column based on aggregate value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been mulling on this problem for a couple of hours now with no luck, so I though people on SO might be able to help :)

I have a table with data regarding processing volumes at stores. The first three columns shown below can be queried from that table. What I'm trying to do is to add a 4th column that's basically a flag regarding if a store has processed >=$150, and if so, will display the corresponding date. The way this works is the first instance where the store has surpassed $150 is the date that gets displayed. Subsequent processing volumes don't count after the the first instance the activated date is hit. For example, for store 4, there's just one instance of the activated date.

```
store_id  sales_volume   date        activated_date
----------------------------------------------------    
2         5              03/14/2012    
2         125            05/21/2012   
2         30             11/01/2012   11/01/2012    
3         100            02/06/2012
3         140            12/22/2012   12/22/2012
4         300            10/15/2012   10/15/2012
4         450            11/25/2012
5         100            12/03/2012
```

Any insights as to how to build out this fourth column? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which versions of PostgreSQL are you interested in?

Comment: 8.3 unfortunately. The window functions that people have suggested below work from 8.4 onwards.

Comment: That's why I asked, window functions (which PostgreSQL gained support for in 8.4) are a natural fit for this sort of thing. Any chance that you can upgrade to 8.4? 8.3 is near (or already at) its end of life.

Answer (score 1):

The solution start by calculating the cumulative sales.  Then, you want the activation date only when the cumulative sales first pass through the $150 level.  This happens when adding the current sales amount pushes the cumulative amount over the threshold.  The following `case` expression handles this.

```
select t.store_id, t.sales_volume, t.date,
       (case when 150 > cumesales - t.sales_volume and 150 <= cumesales
             then date
        end) as ActivationDate
from (select t.*,
             sum(sales_volume) over (partition by store_id order by date) as cumesales
      from t
     ) t
```

If you have an older version of Postgres that does not support cumulative sum, you can get the cumulative sales with a subquery like:

```
(select sum(sales_volume) from t t2 where t2.store_id = t.store_id and t2.date <= t.date) as cumesales
```

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome! I used the subquery approach but got to learn the cumulative sum for future use! Also, I just bought your book and am excited to give it a whirl!

Answer (score 1):

#### Variant 1

You can `LEFT JOIN` to a table that calculates the first date surpassing the 150 $ limit per store:

```
SELECT t.*, b.activated_date
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT store_id, min(thedate) AS activated_date
   FROM  (
      SELECT store_id, thedate
            ,sum(sales_volume) OVER (PARTITION BY store_id
                                     ORDER BY thedate) AS running_sum
      FROM   tbl
      ) a
   WHERE  running_sum >= 150
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) b ON t.store_id = b.store_id AND t.thedate = b.activated_date
ORDER  BY t.store_id, t.thedate;
```

The calculation of the the first day has to be done in two steps, since the window function accumulating the running sum has to be applied in a separate `SELECT`.

#### Variant 2

Another window function instead of the `LEFT JOIN`. May of may not be faster. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN running_sum >= 150 AND thedate = first_value(thedate)
               OVER (PARTITION BY store_id, running_sum >= 150 ORDER BY thedate)
       THEN thedate END AS activated_date
FROM  (
   SELECT *
         ,sum(sales_volume)
              OVER (PARTITION BY store_id ORDER BY thedate) AS running_sum
   FROM   tbl
   ) b
ORDER  BY store_id, thedate;
```

[->sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9c507/6) demonstrating both.

Comment: Thank you! I was wracking my brain over this and eventually got around to doing it using Excel but this is awesome! Will definitely help me save time.